# A house or the house a number or the number

Tags: articles

Should I use the indefinite or the definite article before "number" and "house" when talking about them generally as in my sentence and can the article be omitted before "office"?

"All houses have their own numbers. If you don't say *a/the number* of *the/a* house or office, other people can get lost or will not reach the place."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**number** is definite, because it's the specific number of a house.

**house** is indefinite, because it relates to any house.

The article is optional before **office** because it is part of a parallel construction, with **or** as a coordinating conjunction. With parallel consturctions, repeated words can be omitted.